# Change the background of an individual cell/item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in Android and I want each cell (or item if you will) to have a unique background which is a `GradientDrawable` object.
Here's relevant code chunks:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTextView;
        private LinearLayout mEmotionCell;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.emotionName);
            mEmotionCell = view.findViewById(R.id.emotionCell);
        }

        public void getItem() {

        }
    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final EmotionResponse thisEmotion = mDataSet.get(position);
        final int index = position;
        Tone tone = new EmotionMap().map(mDataSet.get(position).getName());
        ((MyViewHolder)holder).mTextView.setText(thisEmotion.getName());
        ((MyViewHolder)holder).mEmotionCell.setBackground(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.
                Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, new int[] {tone.getStartColor(), tone.getEndColor()}));

    }
```

Where `Tone` is a custom object that I created, and `Tone.getStartColor()` and `Tone.getEndColor()` return integers (logging them shows the values I expected to get so they aren't the issue).
When running the code, the background of each cell remains blank white. Weird thing is, when I try doing `mEmotionCell.setBackgroundColor(some color)`, it does work. So does `mEmotionCell.setBackgroundResource(some drawable resource)`. Only `setBackground` seems to give me trouble. Any ideas?
Here's the XML which is inflated into each cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/emotionCell"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emotionName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, can you give samples of int colors you use in `Tone.getStartColor()` and `Tone.getEndColor()`

Comment: @Zain sure. For example, I'm using `0xa5b6f4`, `0x1a47ec` for start and end colors respectively to get a blue-ish gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working just fine, and the only issue is that in your samples of `Tone.getStartColor()` and `Tone.getEndColor()` (0xa5b6f4, 0x1a47ec) you're using int values without defining the opacity two digits on front of the color code.

The reason you see the blank/white background is that default opacity value is `00` which means that it's full transparent color.

And to get a full opaque color you need to add **`FF`** in front of your colors, for instance in the given colors (0xFFa5b6f4, 0xFF1a47ec).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It never occurred to me that this might be the problem because when I made some gradient drawable resources, I never specified alpha values and they worked properly. Again thank you!

Comment: @YaronGrushka welcome man .. happy coding :) please accept the answer if it kind of help